# can you put an if/else statement inside a tailwind class in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to change the background color of a div and if it is true, the div should have a background color of white, otherwise, it should have a background color of black.

I've tried doing it with a if/else statement but it doesn't seem to work as it always renders the black background.

This is the line I want to change:

```
 <div class="{form ? bg-black : bg-white}">
```

This is my code:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import ClientForm from './clientform.js'

function Clients() {

    const [name, setName] = useState('')
    const [weight, setWeight] = useState('')
    const [BMI, setBMI] = useState('')
    const [form, setForm] = useState(false)

    const toggleForm = () => {
        if(form === false) {
             setForm(true)
        } else {
            setForm(false)
        }
    }

    const submitForm = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()

        const clients = {
            img: 
            { data: Buffer, contentType: String },
          name: name, //reference to the associated book
          weight: weight,
          BMI: BMI
          }
          axios.post('/clients/add', clients)
          .then(res => console.log())
    }

    return (
        <div class="{form ? bg-black : bg-white}">
            <button class="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded" onClick={toggleForm}>New Client</button>
            {form ? <ClientForm /> : void(0)}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Clients
```

Comment: I have a remark replace `if(form === false) ` with `if(!form)` is look better

Comment: @umusi: Or just replace the entire `if` structure with simply: `setForm(!form);`

Answer (score 3):

This is setting the class to just one big string literal that looks like an expression:

```
class="{form ? bg-black : bg-white}"
```

You want to use the expression and have it resolve to a string literal:

```
class={form ? "bg-black" : "bg-white"}
```

---

As an aside, I may be mistaken but I *thought* that in React JSX the `class` attribute needed to be `className`?:

```
className={form ? "bg-black" : "bg-white"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you do `<div class="{form ? 'bg-black : 'bg-white'}">`?

Comment: This wouldn't work for the same reason(s).  The whole expression is still just a string literal.

Answer (score 0):

The right code is:

```html
<div className={form ? "bg-black" : "bg-white"}>
```